# ASP.NET SignalR - Cannot send list of messages stored in database to user

Tags: asp.net, signalr

My SignalR ChatHub requires Authorization in order to send a message to another user. If a users sends a message, but if the recipient is not connected to the Hub, then it will be saved in the database. Now that part works fine, I am able to save messages to the recipients Inbox.

IdentityModel :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{ 
    public virtual ICollection<MyMessage> Inbox { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

This is how messages are saved if not connected to Hub:

```
var recipient = UserManager.FindById(id);
if (recipient != null)
{
    if (recipient.Message_Inbox == null)
    {
        recipient.Message_Inbox = new List<MyMessage>();
    }
    recipient.Inbox.Add(new MyMessage() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), SentBy = userId, Message = message});
    UserManager.Update(recipient); 
}
```

And then OnConnected, the database is queried and the user is sent a list of messages. But that doesn't work. If I create a sample list of messages and send it, my client receives it but not if I send it from the server.

```
List<MyMessage> inbox = user.Inbox.ToList();
Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).sendInbox(inbox); //doesn't work

//but if I do this
List<MyMessage> list = new List<MyMessage>()
                {
                    new MyMessage() { SentBy = "asdsadd", Message = "First", Id = "sds" },
                    new MyMessage() { SentBy = "asdsadd1", Message = "Second", Id = "sds2" },
                };
 Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).sendInbox(list); // IT WORKS
```

This is how I get my UserManager :

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;//updated
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When is _userManager set somewhere? Is the list empty or how doesn’t it work? Are the messages being stored properly somewhere? Just not retrieved?

Comment: Updated the code regarding user manager. The list is not empty. I set a breakpoint when retrieving my inbox, I can see all of the values stored in the list. Message saving works, just unable to retrieve & send them to client.  @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 0):

you will need to change hub method of querying messages to an async action. 
Here's the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asyncmethods).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using Json to serialize it.

```
 string jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inbox);
```

Not sure why my test list didn't need to be serialized, but oh well. It works.